# Can I upload a file to server by socket.io in node.js?

Tags: file-upload, node.js, socket.io

I have a **socket.io client** to whom **socket.io server is listening in node.js**. I want to upload a file to server by `socket.io`. because my `socket.io` client is under apache. and `socket.io` server is in Node.js. I want to code uploading of file in Node.js. But how I can send the file data to the node.js listening to socket.

I have tried the upload of a file using Node.js server. This link is here but the this code does not use the `socket.io` with this. But my original project is using the `socket.io`.

[Uploading a file in node.js by formidable](http://rahulmehta1.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/uploading-a-file-in-node-js-by-formidable/)

How can I do this with the `socket.io` server?

Answer (score 28):

The checked answer is invalid as of Jul 3rd 2012.

Read by yourself [this tutorial on NetTuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/).
This tutorial uses node.js and socket.io to upload a file.

Comment: Do you have any idea about maximum file size that we can upload

Comment: Node/socket.io are stream based, take it with a grain of salt - but there should be no limits.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a module for this purpose.

[socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream)

Comment: Do  you have any idea how to make ios-client that uses it, thanx.

Comment: Using this library was OK until now, I'm using the latest JSPM version and it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a npm module I wrote that will implement Socket.IO file uploading in your application:

[Socket.IO File Upload](https://github.com/vote539/socketio-file-upload)

All you need to give the module is your middleware, your socket, and the file input or drop zone used for uploading files.  It will also save the files if you give it a directory.  The module takes care of the rest.

Comment: @Github scroll down to bottom there is an working example.

Answer (score 6):

In May of 2014 with release version 1.0 of socket.IO, [binary support has been added to the library](http://socket.io/blog/introducing-socket-io-1-0/#binary).

> Socket.IO now supports emitting Buffer (from Node.JS), Blob, ArrayBuffer and even File, as part of any datastructure

It's all due to low level api which is provided by engine.io.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of sending a file over socket.io:
http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/11/12-pushing-files-to-the-browser-using-deliveryjs-socketio-and-nodejs/

Comment: The OP wants to send a file to the server, not to the client as in this example.

Comment: The library from that example ([Delivery.js](https://github.com/liamks/Delivery.js)) claims support for bidirectional file transfers.